# How Can I define rigid plane?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, animation-nodes, rigidbody

I want to pour cubes which are in the image. However when I animate blender p plane passing through to the cubes. How can I solve this problem? I just want to pour cubes and observe falling of cubes when I animate.Can you Help me? 
Thank you...[image]

Comment: Have you applied a Collision Modifier to the plane?

Comment: No , Can you help me?

Comment: Ok so I just realized that you were using animation nodes. Would be easier to actually mention it in your problem description to save time trying to understand the problem. Do you have the same issue when you are not using animation nodes?

Answer (score 0):

***[Final Edit now I think I understand the problem better]***

OK, so I have the same behavior as you if I use your AN setup. Blender expects the passive to not be moving, or you to be explicit about it if it's moving.

So my solution:

Select cube, go to physics, add rigid body, select type active.
Select plane, go to physics, add rigid body, select type passive. Under settings, tick Animated.
Play animation.

It should work.

[image]

Comment: I tried but I cant solve problem?

Comment: Are you sure your plane is passive? I think it should be surrounded by green when selected, not yellow.

Comment: If you solved the problem thanks to an answer from another user, please mark it as answer.